# When I get data from session do i have to validate them again before write into DB?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I store data in a session in this function after validation.

```
  public function result(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'idgroup' => [
                'required', 'numeric', new ExistingGroupMembers, new AdminGroupRequest
            ]
        ]);

    $group = $request->idgroup;
    $groupname = Group::where('id', $group)->select('name')->first();
    $members = V_Member::where([['idgroup', $group],['iduser', '<>', Auth::id()]])->select('iduser', 'username')->get();

    Session::put('exclusion_groupid', $group);
    Session::put('exclusion_groupname', $groupname->name);

    return redirect()->route('user.exclusion');
}
```

Then I get them in another function where I have to store data. Here you can see the store function. I make no validation because I validate the $idgroup variable in the function before.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    $request->validate([
        'member' => [
                'required', 'numeric', new UserPartOfGroup, new MemberAdminRequest
            ]
        ]);

    $iduser = $request->member;
    $idgroup = Session::get('exclusion_groupid');
    $m = Member::where([['member', $iduser],['idgroup', $idgroup]])->first();
    $m->delete();

    $iduser = $m->member;

    return redirect()->action('ExclusionController@create')->with('success', 'Created');
}
```

Is their any way to manipulate the stored session data from a user(hacker)? At the moment I store the session data in files, what should I do in productive run? Store in File, DB or Cookies? What's the best and safest way to do this?

Comment: I didn't see your entire code but I will leave my two cents regarding the `.. data from a user(hacker)?`. Yes. There is. If you open the Google Chrome Developer tools you can just change any value of the session with two or three clicks. Safest way? You won't have a final answer here since this can vary from project to project but the golden rule is: *Always validate the data that can be manipulated by the user (e.g. session, local, cookies, etc...)*

Comment: if you use `$idgroup` directly from session in the `store` function, you will not need to revalidate it. Session Data is stored on server side - it can't be changed from client side (except a "stolen" session (e.g. sessionID or sessionCookie") from another user. so if you are sure you store a valid `idgroup` value in the session at `result` method just use it later :)